# Best way to determine if string is image, youtube, etc

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, I'm looking to code in PHP a function, getType(). This function will take a user inputed string from a web form (in CodeIgniter) and then from there analyze it's content and then determine if the string is a photo (ending in .jpg, .png, etc), a youtube video link, a vimeo video link, or just text.

I'm just having a hard time trying to visualize the best, most economical way to do this.

```
if (strpos($content, ".jpg|.png|.bmp"))
{ return "image"; }
else if (strpos($content, "youtube.com"))
{ return "youtube"; }
else if (strpos($content, "vimeo.com"))
{ return "vimeo" }
else
{ return "text" }
```

Comment: What is the issue with your current code?  I recommend checking if the string ends with an image extension, as someone could input a url with a directory containing one of those extensions to potentially (depending on what you do with the image link) run php scripts with your users' information.  The same applies for the youtube and vimeo urls; you should use a regex for those.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
// check if string ends with image extension
if (preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.png|\.bmp)$/', $content)) {
    return "image";
// check if there is youtube.com in string
} elseif (strpos($content, "youtube.com") !== false) {
    return "youtube";
// check if there is vimeo.com in string
} elseif (strpos($content, "vimeo.com") !== false) {
    return "vimeo";
} else {
    return "text";
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/1V4joK

Note that there is no guarantee that it is a youtube or vimeo link. Because this only checks whether the string matches the service and nothing more.

Comment: Everything works great except the image. I'm quite the regex noob, but should there be a handler for before the attachment name? In regards to the no guarantee, is this the best solution you would suggest?

Comment: @bswinnerton See the demo added to my answer. It seems to work for me. About the filetypes. About the video services. It depends. Do you allow only a specific format of the string for videos. If that is the case you could make the check better.

Comment: The only thing that I'm interested in is grabbing either the youtube/video id or image filename. I still can't get it to return image no matter what I try. I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure the string contains what you think it does? Does it have either of those three extensions. Does my demo work?

Comment: Oddly enough, no. I'm using codeigniter and only the regex isn't working. I'm checking it out now. Even when I pipe in your exact content, I just get the text loop.